# Openfire Java Memory

Tags: openfire

I have openfire installed on my debian server.

I want to know that whether openfire java memory should be less than server memory?

For e.g. i have a server with 256 MB RAM now can i have openfire java memory more than 256 MB RAM or it should be less than 256.

Please help

Thanks, Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find that the JVM won't start if you set the memory too high on your system (something like "Could not reserve enough space for object heap")

How many users are you planning to have? If it's just a few, openfire should run alright with 128MB or so. If you are planning to have more than a dozen active at any one time, you really should look into getting more memory in your server. This is doubly true if you're planning to run a database on the same server. You *don't* want to run Openfire on a server that's running in swap memory.

Another thing - the version of openfire that ships with Debian is probably *really* old. Get the latest version, or at least 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Do not allocate so much as to go into swap. Allocate enough so that the application does not run out of memory. Unless you have lots of activity, further tuning probably won't be very relevant.

Other than that, you will have to strike a balance between devoting memory to Java (I believe the default garbage collector is the nonincremental one, so more memory for the JVM will mean less frequent, but longer pauses) or to disk cache (better IO performance if your working set fits into the cache).

Answer (score 0):

In general when tuning the JVM, you're better off keeping its limits below the amount of physical ram in the system.  Otherwise, you have a strong likelihood that other system processes will get swapped out as the JVM starts hogging all the ram.

Answer (score 0):

Openfire is extremely java hungry, but don't let it go into swap. It will literally crawl.

I'd add more RAM if I were you, 256RAM in total on a Java application server is not common practice (unless it's something -really- lightweight, wich Openfire isn't).